# VB6: what is the likely cause of Error 3078 " ... Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query ... "

Tags: vb6, jet

VB6: what is the likely cause of Error 3078 " ... Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query ... "

Comment: Do you ever create queries as strings, so that you might encounter accidental SQL-injection type errors? Where the data contains ' or " characters which cause the Jet engine to misinterpret your SQL?

Comment: Is the database on the local machine or server based?  All machines or just one?

Trying to rule out network card/traffic/connectivity as an issue.  I've seen that happen at times.

Comment: It is server based. And in this case it is being accessed from a Virtual Machine on the same machine as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the connection and checking the database for corruption, that is, back up and then compact and repair. You might also like to [`read this article on corruption`](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm)

Answer (score 2):

A typo in the table name.

Comment: problem is intermittent - not consistent with a typo in any SQL.

Comment: I've seen this in programs that cobble SQL together on the fly in several parts of the program.  Some code paths will result in a clean query while others lead to a fragmentary result that produces syntax errors or this sort of error.

Comment: Be wary of non-ASCII characters creeping into table names or other parts of the SQL string. These may not appear visibly but can still cause a mismatch. Anecdotal reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother/run-time-error-3078-but-table-name-is-correct/a9465ced-0e6f-4c79-8711-fa544f40ae3c see the Nov 20, 2014 post.